# How can I get this effect (on height) with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kTAKu/) :

## HTML

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px;">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">1 Line</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text</div>
</div>    

<div style="float:left; width:100px;">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">3 Lines</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text<br /> on 3<br> Lines</div>
</div>        

<div style="float:left; width:100px;">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">2 Lines</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text<br /> on 2 Lines</div>
</div>            

<div class="fascia" style="display:none;">
    <div class="openedTab"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.openedTab
{
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

## jQuery

```
$('.openTab').hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.openedTab').html($(this).next().html());

    $('.fascia').slideDown('200', function() { });
    
});​
```

if you hover a link, you can see the `slideDown()` in action (it scroll making animation).
Now, I'd like to have this animation to the max height for each div when I go hover it.

I mean : if I go on Link1 and than on Link2, I want to see the scroll to the bottom, starting from the height of Link1. Also, from Link2 to Link3, it must scroll to the top, till it get the height of content of link3.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the div height of the ".fascia", then the .slideDown will work as you please.
You can always use .animate() and set the needed css with it.

EDIT:

To clarify, for a completely dynamic maximum height, you need to go through each element, determine their height and store the maximum value. Then add this to the desired element.

if you really wanted a dynamic height:

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px;" class="line">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">1 Line</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text</div>
</div>    

<div style="float:left; width:100px;" class="line">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">3 Lines</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text<br /> on 3<br> Lines</div>
</div>        

<div style="float:left; width:100px;" class="line">
    <a class="openTab" href="http://www.link.it">2 Lines</a>
    <div style="display:none;">My Text<br /> on 2 Lines</div>
</div>            

<div class="fascia" style="display:none;">
    <div class="openedTab"></div>
</div>
```

​

JavaScript

```
var elements = $('.line div'),
maxH = 0;

$.each(elements,function(key,val){
    var elH = $(elements[key]).css('display','').height();
    maxH = (elH > maxH) ? elH : maxH;
    $(elements[key]).css('display','none');
});

$('.fascia div').height(maxH);

$('.openTab').hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.openedTab').html($(this).next().html());

    $('.fascia').slideDown('200', function() { });

});​
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, but the height of '.fascia' is dynamic, due to openedTab content height :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the height of the div before and after the animation. You could store the height of the div, set the new content and store the new height. Now you set the height of the div back to the old value and start the animation.

[Quick and dirty example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sg4b/)

## HTML

```
...
<div class="fascia">
    <div class="openedTab"></div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
$('.openTab').hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.openedTab').stop(true, true);

    var heightBefore = $('.openedTab').height();

    $('.openedTab').html($(this).next().html());

    var heightAfter = $('.openedTab').height();

    $('.openedTab').height(heightBefore);

    $('.openedTab').animate({
        height: heightAfter + "px"
    }, 200, function() {
        $(this).height('auto');
    });    
});​
```

​